# Is it possible to know the path to the FitNesse directory (root) from within a FitNesse page?

Tags: fitnesse

Is it possible to know what the FitNesse directory is from within a FitNesse page? I need to reference files with path relative to the FitNesse directory.

Thanks

Comment: What kinds of things do you want to do with these files? Would you be performing some kind of operation to them in a fixture? Do you have control of your fixture and where it is loaded from? If so then you could run the files relative to the fixture.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like test require files and you try specify file path thru root path. Am I right? You could configure fitnesse thru [`COMMAND_PATTERN`](http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.CustomizingTestExecution) and specify root path as var. Here is config example

Run but

```
java -Xmx100M -Dtestserver.Configuration=Debug -jar fitnesse.jar -p 88 -e 0 -d %~dp0

pause
```

First Page

```
#
!*> Define variables

!define CONFIGURATION {${testserver.Configuration}}
!define TESTSDIRECTORY {..\Out\${CONFIGURATION}\FitNesseTests}

!define COMMAND_PATTERN {%m -a ${TESTSDIRECTORY}\FitNesseTests.dll.config -r fitnesse.fitserver.FitServer,${TESTSDIRECTORY}\fit.dll %p} 
!define TEST_RUNNER {${TESTSDIRECTORY}\Runner.exe} 
!path ${TESTSDIRECTORY}\*.dll

!define DATASTORE_PATH {${TESTSDIRECTORY}\DataStore}

!define COLLAPSE_SETUP {true}
!define COLLAPSE_TEARDOWN {true}

*!
#

!contents -R2
```

Now you can use `DATASTORE_PATH` as data store folder.

Comment: well, in the original question I did not mention that I was calling FitNesse from JUnit as in 

https://github.com/unclebob/fitnesse/blob/master/src/fitnesse/junit/FitNesseSuiteExampleTest.java

and I would not know how to pass variables to it when invoking it from JUnit.